# How to I substitute variables defined within liquibase.properties via spring-boot property files?

Tags: spring-boot, liquibase

I understand, variable substitution is achievable in a liquibase.properties file using the following format:

```
driver: @spring.datasource.driver-class-name@
```

This will work if variables are passed as JVM args, but what I would like to do is source these variables from spring boot property files. I've got my JDBC/username and encrypted passwords in each env file but when I select my spring profile, the app fails to start and the logs show the variables haven't been substituted.

Is there a way to achieve this or is my approach wrong?

Comment: Why do you want to use `liquibase.properties` if you are using Spring Boot ? What version on Spring Boot are you using ?

Comment: 2.2.5. You could be right. I actually picked this code up from elsewhere and didn't consider that I could just remove liquibase.properties and have the values defined in each profile. I'll give that a try and see how I get on.

Comment: My version is 2.1.3, but here's an example of mine with Liquibase and Spring Boot if that can help you : https://github.com/GabLeg/springboot-example. Liquibase use the `spring.datasource` properties to connect to the database.

Comment: @GabLeg, your code is a very good example :) and it confirms you can indeed just remove the liquibase properties. The only outstanding issue here is how to deal with the schema name in the change log. So, I've got <createTable schemaName="@schema.name@" tableName="blah">. This isn't getting updated via the property. I'm not even sure if this is possible.

Comment: @GabLeg Nm, found what I needed: spring.liquibase.parameters.<blah>. Now I just need to sort out my oracle permissions and I'm on easy street. Thanks for your help!

Comment: `@Desolate Planet` Glad that my code helped you :)